# Looking for info on interfacing with ANT+ sensors for a Windows application

Tags: c#, windows

I'm a triathlete and have been looking for a way to capture data from the ANT+ devices on my bike.  I'm a C# developer and figure there has to be a way to do this but I don't know where to start.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start here. Official site.
http://www.thisisant.com/developer/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I stumbled upon that page after a little more digging around.  Stack *always* has the answers, and now it has this one as well!